# Im Trying to create a Deepfake in Jupyter notebook but its saying a module isn't found

Tags: python

i executed this code:

```
from demo import load_checkpoints
generator, kp_detector = load_checkpoints(config_path='config/vox-256.yaml', 
                            checkpoint_path='/content/gdrive/My Drive/first-order-motion-model/vox-cpk.pth.tar')
```

after executing, it thrown this error sayng that im missing a module called demo:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-aac07a390ef5> in <module>()
     10 import libarchive
     11 
---> 12 from demo import load_checkpoints
     13 generator, kp_detector = load_checkpoints(config_path='config/vox-256.yaml', 
     14                             checkpoint_path='/content/gdrive/My Drive/first-order-motion-model/vox-cpk.pth.tar')

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demo'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I followed the Instructions on the Note. I added one !pip and two !apt commands before the main code.

```
!pip install cartopy
import cartopy

# https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydot
!apt-get -qq install -y graphviz && pip install pydot
import pydot

# https://pypi.python.org/pypi/libarchive
!apt-get -qq install -y libarchive-dev && pip install -U libarchive
import libarchive

from demo import load_checkpoints
generator, kp_detector = load_checkpoints(config_path='config/vox-256.yaml', 
                            checkpoint_path='/content/gdrive/My Drive/first-order-motion-model/vox-cpk.pth.tar')
```

but it throws the same error. I dont know what to do now beacuse im doing a school project about Deepfakes and my teacher requested me to make an example of a Deepfake. I found a simple tutorial page about how to do it but they doesnt say a word about errors. I have 0 knowledge about coding so again, i dont know what to do to fix this issue. If someone replies, thanks.

```
Collecting cartopy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/46/c1/04e50c9986842f00f7db0e7a65caa896840050d7328f74e5b7437aa01179/Cartopy-0.18.0.tar.gz (14.4MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 14.4MB 229kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from cartopy) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: shapely>=1.5.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from cartopy) (1.7.1)
Collecting pyshp>=1.1.4
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/38/85/fbf87e7aa55103e0d06af756bdbc15cf821fa580414c23142d60a35d4f85/pyshp-2.1.3.tar.gz (219kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 225kB 46.0MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from cartopy) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=0.7.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from cartopy) (54.1.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: cartopy, pyshp
  Building wheel for cartopy (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for cartopy: filename=Cartopy-0.18.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl size=15127707 sha256=a654609daeabe10086e2283a53e85918564f6eeb193a30c16acc8c117cc7108b
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/8d/f8/da/2c05136f2162370d2baec85bfbbf91d7729ab9e248da878acd
  Building wheel for pyshp (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for pyshp: filename=pyshp-2.1.3-cp37-none-any.whl size=37264 sha256=fb70034866333f4cb28a6d1a447eddf047eb9e4c0e40afc257fac9d5d1d4b947
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/76/2b/d4/53e6b9a0fb0a9f9f29664cf82605af8bc81d5ab44d987896dd
Successfully built cartopy pyshp
Installing collected packages: pyshp, cartopy
Successfully installed cartopy-0.18.0 pyshp-2.1.3
Requirement already satisfied: pydot in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.1.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pydot) (2.4.7)
Selecting previously unselected package libarchive-dev:amd64.
(Reading database ... 160980 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libarchive-dev_3.2.2-3.1ubuntu0.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libarchive-dev:amd64 (3.2.2-3.1ubuntu0.6) ...
Setting up libarchive-dev:amd64 (3.2.2-3.1ubuntu0.6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Collecting libarchive
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bf/d4/26f5c9835d4d648e4f22b5fb91288457698e928aaf9d4ab7eff405b7ef03/libarchive-0.4.7.tar.gz
Collecting nose
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/15/d8/dd071918c040f50fa1cf80da16423af51ff8ce4a0f2399b7bf8de45ac3d9/nose-1.3.7-py3-none-any.whl (154kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 6.9MB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: libarchive
  Building wheel for libarchive (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for libarchive: filename=libarchive-0.4.7-cp37-none-any.whl size=31633 sha256=84002f656d8b4ff6394a0b9b122bbba28ce6781884855c6f6b81ac52abef0488
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/3b/5c/fa/92ee330d259e8fa5bedbd53f67040710fe81cfa463b8711d26
Successfully built libarchive
Installing collected packages: nose, libarchive
Successfully installed libarchive-0.4.7 nose-1.3.7
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-aac07a390ef5> in <module>()
     10 import libarchive
     11 
---> 12 from demo import load_checkpoints
     13 generator, kp_detector = load_checkpoints(config_path='config/vox-256.yaml', 
     14                             checkpoint_path='/content/gdrive/My Drive/first-order-motion-model/vox-cpk.pth.tar')

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demo'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

https://colab.research.google.com/github/AliaksandrSiarohin/first-order-model/blob/master/demo.ipynb#scrollTo=3FQiXqQPWt5B&uniqifier=5
```

https://www.kapwing.com/resources/baka-mitai-dame-da-ne-meme/

Comment: Your error says it expects some file/folder available named "demo" from where you're running the code, so you cannot simply code-paste sections of a tutorial

Comment: In particular, you're missing this, and maybe other stuff - https://github.com/AliaksandrSiarohin/first-order-model/blob/master/demo.py

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is referring to not being able to import the 'demo' module, and there are two possible reasons for that:

1. You don't have "demo" installed from the public PyPi repository. This is where publicly available packages are published. The "pip install" command will usually fetch packages from PyPi.
2. You are are missing part of the codebase for your project -- specifically a file called "demo.py".

In your case, you are missing number 2. The code for the project you are working on is found in the [Github repository for the demo](https://github.com/AliaksandrSiarohin/first-order-model), and you can see the file demo.py in the top level of the folder structure. To me, it looks like you didn't actually run the first part of the code:

```
!git clone https://github.com/AliaksandrSiarohin/first-order-model
```

Comment: Sorry, i absolutely forgot that the Input video must 30 seconds or less.
Everything is ok now. I will try to close the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Still throwing errors. I also made sure i didnt skip Executing the First Block of Code.

!git clone https://github.com/AliaksandrSiarohin/first-order-model

!pip install demo-py

from demo import load_checkpoints
generator, kp_detector = load_checkpoints(config_path='config/vox-256.yaml',
checkpoint_path='/content/gdrive/My Drive/first-order-motion-model/vox-cpk.pth.tar')

### fatal: destination path 'first-order-model' already exists and is not an empty directory.
Requirement already satisfied: demo-py in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (0.0.1a8)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-contrib-nbextensions in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from demo-py) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: spacy>=2.3.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from demo-py) (3.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from demo-py) (3.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: ipywidgets in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from demo-py) (7.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from demo-py) (5.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from demo-py) (1.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: nbconvert>=4.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from jupyter-contrib-nbextensions->demo-py) (5.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-nbextensions-configurator>=0.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from jupyter-contrib-nbextensions->demo-py) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-highlight-selected-word>=0.1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from jupyter-contrib-nbextensions->demo-py) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-latex-envs>=1.3.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from jupyter-contrib-nbextensions->demo-py) (1.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from jupyter-contrib-nbextensions->demo-py) (5.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from jupyter-contrib-nbextensions->demo-py) (3.13)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from jupyter-contrib-nbextensions->demo-py) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-contrib-core>=0.3.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from jupyter-contrib-nbextensions->demo-py) (0.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from jupyter-contrib-nbextensions->demo-py) (4.2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from jupyter-contrib-nbextensions->demo-py) (4.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from jupyter-contrib-nbextensions->demo-py) (5.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: notebook>=4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from jupyter-contrib-nbextensions->demo-py) (5.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: catalogue<2.1.0,>=2.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (2.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.8.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (0.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: srsly<3.0.0,>=2.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (2.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions<4.0.0.0,>=3.7.4; python_version < "3.8" in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (3.7.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (2.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: blis<0.8.0,>=0.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: typer<0.4.0,>=0.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (0.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.38.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (4.41.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (2.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pydantic<1.8.0,>=1.7.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (1.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (3.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pathy>=0.3.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (0.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: thinc<8.1.0,>=8.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (8.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: spacy-legacy<3.1.0,>=3.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (1.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (54.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata>=0.20; python_version < "3.8" in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (3.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (20.9)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib->demo-py) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib->demo-py) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib->demo-py) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib->demo-py) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel>=4.5.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from ipywidgets->demo-py) (4.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyterlab-widgets>=1.0.0; python_version >= "3.6" in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from ipywidgets->demo-py) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nbformat>=4.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from ipywidgets->demo-py) (5.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from ipywidgets->demo-py) (3.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from ipython->demo-py) (1.0.18)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from ipython->demo-py) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: simplegeneric>0.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from ipython->demo-py) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect; sys_platform != "win32" in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from ipython->demo-py) (4.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from ipython->demo-py) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from ipython->demo-py) (2.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pandas->demo-py) (2018.9)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints>=0.2.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from nbconvert>=4.2->jupyter-contrib-nbextensions->demo-py) (0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: testpath in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from nbconvert>=4.2->jupyter-contrib-nbextensions->demo-py) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from nbconvert>=4.2->jupyter-contrib-nbextensions->demo-py) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: mistune<2,>=0.8.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from nbconvert>=4.2->jupyter-contrib-nbextensions->demo-py) (0.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pandocfilters>=1.4.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from nbconvert>=4.2->jupyter-contrib-nbextensions->demo-py) (1.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: bleach in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from nbconvert>=4.2->jupyter-contrib-nbextensions->demo-py) (3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client>=5.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from notebook>=4.0->jupyter-contrib-nbextensions->demo-py) (5.3.5)
Requirement already satisfied: Send2Trash in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from notebook>=4.0->jupyter-contrib-nbextensions->demo-py) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: terminado>=0.8.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from notebook>=4.0->jupyter-contrib-nbextensions->demo-py) (0.9.2)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (2020.12.5)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (1.24.3)
Requirement already satisfied: click<7.2.0,>=7.1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from typer<0.4.0,>=0.3.0->spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from jinja2->spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: smart-open<4.0.0,>=2.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pathy>=0.3.5->spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from importlib-metadata>=0.20; python_version < "3.8"->spacy>=2.3.2->demo-py) (3.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib->demo-py) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets->demo-py) (2.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.4->ipython->demo-py) (0.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess>=0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pexpect; sys_platform != "win32"->ipython->demo-py) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from bleach->nbconvert>=4.2->jupyter-contrib-nbextensions->demo-py) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=13 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from jupyter-client>=5.2.0->notebook>=4.0->jupyter-contrib-nbextensions->demo-py) (22.0.3)

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
3 get_ipython().system('pip install demo-py')
4
----> 5 from demo import load_checkpoints
6 generator, kp_detector = load_checkpoints(config_path='config/vox-256.yaml',
7                             checkpoint_path='/content/gdrive/My Drive/first-order-motion-model/vox-cpk.pth.tar')

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demo'

---

NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

### To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.

Answer (score 0):

One of my friends recommended me adding demo.py manualy into the Goodgle Drive Folder.
That helped for one try but now i got stuck at "Preform image Animation"

from demo import make_animation
from skimage import img_as_ubyte

predictions = make_animation(source_image, driving_video, generator, kp_detector, relative=True)

#save resulting video
imageio.mimsave('../generated.mp4', [img_as_ubyte(frame) for frame in predictions], fps=fps)
#video can be downloaded from /content folder

HTML(display(source_image, driving_video, predictions).to_html5_video())

Log:

Timestamp   Level   Message
Mar 25, 2021, 11:09:39 AM   WARNING WARNING:root:kernel ce4cbcbb-2a51-4c3f-8e25-24389f444623 restarted
Mar 25, 2021, 11:09:39 AM   INFO    KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
Mar 25, 2021, 11:08:13 AM   WARNING tcmalloc: large alloc 1345585152 bytes == 0x5601ed3a6000 @ 0x7ff6df0431e7 0x7ff6d64b946e 0x7ff6d6509c7b 0x7ff6d6509d97 0x7ff6d65a2887 0x560001d36050 0x560001e2799d 0x560001da9fe9 0x560001da4b0e 0x560001d3777a 0x560001da686a 0x560001da4b0e 0x560001da4813 0x560001da2cc0 0x560001d35ee9 0x560001d35de0 0x560001da9ac2 0x560001da4b0e 0x560001d3777a 0x560001da5c9e 0x560001da4b0e 0x560001d3777a 0x560001da686a 0x560001da4e0d 0x560001d3802c 0x560001d38231 0x560001da71e6 0x560001da4e0d 0x560001d3777a 0x560001da686a 0x560001da4b0e
Mar 25, 2021, 11:08:11 AM   WARNING tcmalloc: large alloc 2691170304 bytes == 0x5600dfd8c000 @ 0x7ff6df0431e7 0x7ff6d64b946e 0x7ff6d6509c7b 0x7ff6d650ce83 0x7ff6d650d07b 0x7ff6d65ae761 0x560001d36050 0x560001d35de0 0x560001daa244 0x560001da4b0e 0x560001d3777a 0x560001da686a 0x560001da4b0e 0x560001da4813 0x560001da2cc0 0x560001d35ee9 0x560001d35de0 0x560001da9ac2 0x560001da4b0e 0x560001d3777a 0x560001da5c9e 0x560001da4b0e 0x560001d3777a 0x560001da686a 0x560001da4e0d 0x560001d3802c 0x560001d38231 0x560001da71e6 0x560001da4e0d 0x560001d3777a 0x560001da686a
Mar 25, 2021, 11:04:26 AM   INFO    Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel ce4cbcbb-2a51-4c3f-8e25-24389f444623
Mar 25, 2021, 11:04:24 AM   INFO    Kernel started: ce4cbcbb-2a51-4c3f-8e25-24389f444623
Mar 25, 2021, 11:03:46 AM   INFO    Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
Mar 25, 2021, 11:03:46 AM   INFO    http://172.28.0.2:9000/
Mar 25, 2021, 11:03:46 AM   INFO    The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
Mar 25, 2021, 11:03:46 AM   INFO    0 active kernels